# Is there a way to tell composer to use only the contents of one folder in a git repo?

Tags: php, git, github, phpunit, composer-php

I have several small projects (`php`) with unit tests (`phpUnit`) managed by VCS (`git`) and published open source (`github`).  I want to use these small projects as dependencies in larger projects using dependency manager (`composer`).

The repo is structured:

```
/src/(files I want referenced by composer)
/phpUnit/(unit tests)
/doc/(documentation)
/(License & other meta-data)
```

When someone uses `composer` to load these small projects, I only want the contents of `/src` returned into the appropriate folder in the bigger project.

Is there a way to do this?  I have been searching but haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

If those files are in different subfolders of `composer/src/`, then you can add those repos as **[submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)** of the composer repo.

```
cd /path/to/composer
git submodule add -- /url/to/subrepo src/subrepo
```

Then a simple `git clone --recusive /url/to/composer` will clone everything.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.gitattributes` file as follows:

```
/phpUnit export-ignore
/doc export-ignore
/license export-ignore
(add all other metadata files here as well)
```

Github will exclude these files and directories in the zip files it creates for releases, so if users install the package with `--prefer-dist` the excluded files will not be installed.

> But really I am more looking at pointing exclusively to one of the sub-directories (`/src`).

That's impossible. Composer is a *package* manager and since a package is meant to be a cohesive unit, it does not make sense to install it partially.

Comment: This fixes one of my problems.  But really I am more looking at pointing exclusively to one of the sub-directories (`/src`).